# How can I change the font of ttk.OptionMenu?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, optionmenu

I can't change the font of the ttk.OptionMenu. I've tried using styles, but it didn't work:

```
...
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('my.TOptionMenu', font=('Arial', 30, 'bold'))
...
self.option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(self.dict_frame, self.option_menu_variable, *[None],style='my.TOptionMenu')
self.option_menu.pack(side='left')
...
error:
self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: Layout TOptionMenu not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `ttk.OptionMenu` uses the style `TMenubutton`:

```
opt_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(root, tk.StringVar())

opt_menu.winfo_class()

# 'TMenubutton'
```

When you refer to `TOptionMenu` style `tkinter` wasn't able to reference it and gave you the error.  Given that, just change your `style` as such:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('my.TMenubutton', font=('Arial', 30, 'bold'))
...
self.option_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(self.dict_frame, self.option_menu_variable, *[None],style='my.TMenubutton')
self.option_menu.pack(side='left')
```

And now it should work.